# Parallel implemention of Lisp-style mapping of a function to a list in C++ fails without cout after use of thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, dictionary, stdthread

This code works only when any of the lines under `/* debug messages */` are uncommented. Or if the list being mapped to is less than 30 elements.

`func_map` is a linear implementation of a Lisp-style mapping and can be assumed to work.

Use of it would be as follows `func_map(FUNC_PTR foo, std::vector* list, locs* start_and_end)`

`FUNC_PTR` is a pointer to a function that returns `void` and takes in an `int` pointer

For example: `&foo` in which `foo` is defined as:

```
void foo (int* num){ (*num) = (*num) * (*num);}
```

`locs` is a struct with two members `int_start` and `int_end`; I use it to tell `func_map` which elements it should iterate over.

```
void par_map(FUNC_PTR func_transform, std::vector<int>* vector_array) //function for mapping a function to a list alla lisp
{
    int array_size = (*vector_array).size(); //retain the number of elements in our vector
    int num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); //figure out number of cores    
    int array_sub = array_size/num_threads; //number that we use to figure out how many elements should be assigned per thread

    std::vector<std::thread> threads; //the vector that we will initialize threads in
    std::vector<locs> vector_locs; // the vector that we will store the start and end position for each thread

    for(int i = 0; i < num_threads && i < array_size; i++)
    {
        locs cur_loc; //the locs struct that we will create using the power of LOGIC
        if(array_sub == 0) //the LOGIC
        {
            cur_loc.int_start = i; //if the number of elements in the array is less than the number of cores just assign one core to each element
        }
        else
        {
            cur_loc.int_start = (i * array_sub); //otherwise figure out the starting point given the number of cores
        }

        if(i == (num_threads - 1))
        {
            cur_loc.int_end = array_size; //make sure all elements will be iterated over
        }
        else if(array_sub == 0)
        {
            cur_loc.int_end = (i + 1); //ditto
        }
            else
            {
                cur_loc.int_end = ((i+1) * array_sub); //otherwise use the number of threads to determine our ending point
            }

        vector_locs.push_back(cur_loc); //store the created locs struct so it doesnt get changed during reference
        threads.push_back(std::thread(func_map,
                                  func_transform,
                                   vector_array,
                                    (&vector_locs[i]))); //create a thread

        /*debug messages*/ // <--- whenever any of these are uncommented the code works
        //cout << "i = " << i << endl;
        //cout << "int_start == " << cur_loc.int_start << endl;
        //cout << "int_end == " << cur_loc.int_end << endl << endl;
        //cout << "Thread " << i << " initialized" << endl; 

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < num_threads && i < array_size; i++)
    {
        (threads[i]).join(); //make sure all the threads are done
    }
}
```

I think that the issue might be in how `vector_locs[i]` is used and how threads are resolved. But the use of a vector to maintain the state of the `locs` instance referenced by thread should prevent that from being an issue; I'm really stumped.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. It would be simpler to include the line: `typedef void (*FUNC_PTR)(int *);` than to explain what it is.  It's more precise, and more concise. I've not spent time studying your code, but when I'm told "the problem isn't _here_", that's one of the first places I look for the actual trouble.  Since you've not provided that code, we can't actually look, but I'm immediately suspicious.  How do you know that code (`func_map`) is sound?  (Also, FYI, `&foo` and just `foo` amount to the same thing. That's completely tangential to the issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving the thread function a pointer, `&vector_locs[i]`, that may become invalidated as you `push_back` more items into the vector.
Since you know beforehand how many items `vector_locs` will contain - `min(num_threads, array_size)` - you can `reserve` that space in advance to prevent reallocation.

As to why it doesn't crash if you uncomment the output, I would guess that the output is so slow that the thread you just started will finish before the output is done, so the next iteration can't affect it.

Comment: That seems to have fixed the problem. It looks like you were right about how the pointers changed as more elements were added to the list. Thanks a bunch for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make this loop inner to the main one:

```
 ...
 for(int i = 0; i < num_threads && i < array_size; i++)
 {
   (threads[i]).join(); //make sure all the threads are done
 }
}
```

Comment: That would actually slow down the code to the speed of a linear implementation because it would cause the program to wait for each thread to finish before initiating the next one.